# wxPython : Change label of "Browse" button in wxFilePickerCtrl object

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wxPython 4.2.0 for python 3.10.8 through wxFormBuilder and I can't find a way to change the label of the "Browse" button of my wxFilePicker object. I want to change this label because my application's language is not English and I'd like to have language coherency over the whole interface and to avoid confusing non-english speaking users. To be clear, the object is working perfectly, I'd just like to change the label of the button.
I already searched for similar questions and in the documentation but there's nothing on this specific label.

I want to know if it's possible at all to change this label while still using the very practical wxFilePickerCtrl, and if so, how. If it's impossible, I'll just leave the label as is.

Comment: You could try changing the style "wx.FLP_SMALL: Use smaller version of the control with a small “…” button instead of the normal “Browse” one." See [here](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.FilePickerCtrl.html?highlight=filepickerctrl#wx.FilePickerCtrl)

Comment: It's not ideal, but it's the closest to what I need, so it's a good compromise, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this, as I use Linux, which uses a bitmap rather than a `Browse` button but I assume that once you have created the `filepickerctrl` you can simply adjust the values, as follows:

```
self.fp_ctrl = wx.FilePickerCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, message="Choose a file")
self.fp_ctrl.SetLabel("MyLabel")
self.fp_ctrl.SetLabelText("LabelText")
self.fp_ctrl.SetToolTip("MyLabel Tip")
```

I assume at least one of the above will be useful but as I said, it is an assumption.

Based on your comment, the easiest answer then, is roll your own e.g:

```
import  wx

class MyPicker(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=title, size=(-1, 535))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.filehandle = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, (''), style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.select_button = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_OPEN, "&Navegar")
        self.select_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)
        sizer.Add(self.filehandle, 1, wx.ALL, 10)
        sizer.Add(self.select_button, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, event):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, style=wx.FD_OPEN|wx.FD_PREVIEW, wildcard="*.png")
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.filehandle.SetValue(dlg.GetPath())
        dlg.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
MyPicker(title="File Picker")
app.MainLoop()
```

This restricts file selection to `png` files only with the wildcard argument, just for testing.

[image]

Comment: Sadly no : SetLabel and SetLabelText seem to have absolutely no effect, and SetToolTip only adds a floating rectangle containing "MyLabel Tip" when the control is hovered over (I tried them directly in the main window constructor to make sure they would be called). I might still use tool-tips if I can't find a way to change the label directly.

Comment: See my updated example

Comment: So I guess the answer is no : it's impossible to change the label of the wxFilePicker object. I'll see with the users if I have to make a custom button later but it'll stay default for now.